# Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{(\cos\theta)^x+(\sin\theta)^x-1}{x-2}, \theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \frac{(\cos\theta)^x+(\sin\theta)^x-1}{x-2}, \theta \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I've tried rationalizing, reducing it, etc. but I'm not getting anywhere. And by the way, I'm not allowed to use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: which rules can you use?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Pretty much everything except L'Hopital's.

Comment: Hint: It is the derivative of some function at $x=2$.

Comment: that's true due to l'hopital?  But why otherwise?

Comment: Let me repeat @Sawarnik's hint: The limit to be computed is a derivative $f'(2)$ for some well chosen function $f$. So, the task is to recognize that the ratios are $$\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$$ for some well chosen function $f$, and then to compute $f'(2)$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Write $1=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$

Now set $x-2=u$  in $$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{a^x-a^2}{x-2}=a^2\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{a^u-1}u=a^2\ln a$$ using  $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1$ and $a=e^{\ln a}$